# VSE how to transition from one video strip to another with effect like turning (flipping) page?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I would like to setup a video transition that looks like if you were turning a book page (with the current strip image) so that the new video strip appears after page is turned.

Is there a way to do this transition in BLENDER VSE?

Comment: Not only in the VSE, but you could do something and in the 3D viewport and compositor i.e. you could make a green page, and a blue page, and use a color key node to key out each color in the compositor.  Then render this and throw it into the VSE. Repeat for each time you need to transition.  For example, throughout my recent [video](https://youtu.be/ctX44HRtgYQ) (see 2:10 for example), I made a custom transition with a tardis. I animated green between the doors at the beginning, and then keyed out the green and replaced it with the end of an animation in the compositor.

Comment: Just adding to @Shady Puck's  comment, you might find it easier to model the turning page (plane sudivded and rolled back with bones?)  firstly, outputting the video as PNG files using the OpenGL renderer, that are Alpha Layered so all behind it is invisible.  Use that in the VSE to lay on top of the page underneath.  Alpha layer doesn't require Chroma-key compositing - it just happens!

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I am actually looking for a simpler approach, the intention is only to perform a transition, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsmO3cubw_o

Comment: @bruno: I guess you looked for a prebuilt transition like that. If you just looked for this, the answer is no, blender's vse doesn't have such fancy prebuilt effects.

Answer (score 1):

In VSE I don't know how. However you can model a book, and on the pages you can build a double sided material: you need a geometry node with "backfacing" connected to the fac of a mix shader node. Connected to the mix shader's shader slots, will be the 2 movies/image sequences you want for the transition. Next, you just need to rotate the page as you want/need. There are tutorials on model a book or animate the pages, like this one: https://vimeo.com/11232299 node setup would be something like this https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=154566&d=1316065621&thumb=1
I talked to a friend and he recommended a external free software called VSDC video editor, as it is easier to acomplish this (http://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor/download)

Answer (score 1):

The VSE is not built not make 3D effects. But neither were the edit systems of last century and they could do it. So lets try.

[image: Peel effect in VSE]

First thing to do is grab 2 source images to transition between.

Then decide how long the transition will be. This is important as the effect is made up of wipes which are variable length and animated transform effects, which you'll need to modify by moving keyframes.

[image: Initial image strips]

Notice that the wipe goes from the background image to the Metastrip stack. It is labelled Wipe Background. 
***The next part is key!***
There is a wipe from the Wipe Background metastrip to the incoming shot, it is called Wipe Incoming. They are both oriented at 45 degrees.

Inside the Metastrip is the rotated and translated image, there is also a drop shadow and highlight effect.

[image: Metastrip peel effect]

At the bottom is a duplicate of the source image strip and an adjustment layer. *I use an adjustment layer in case I want to swap out the source image for some other shot.*

Then the adjustment layer gets a transform effect strip that is rotates the image 90 degrees, anti-clockwise and moved to the top right corner. This is animated to the lower left corner. When you add a wipe of the same duration it looks like a page peel.

First I add a Gaussian blur to the Transform strip, then I duplicate the Transform layer above the blur strip. The first transform effect gets a Curves modifier to make it all black, this will be the drop shadow.

[image: Peel shadow]

Above the Transform effect strip I add a a color effect and make it all white. Then I add the same wipe between the white and the Transform strip. When you soften the wipe it makes a fake Highlight.

[image: Peel highlight]

The metastrip can quickly be altered to work with any source strip, but the wipes will have to be applied to the strips. Although you could add an Adjustment effect strip to the incoming strip, making it a completely stand alone effect.